# d3.js - how to animate a group attributes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a group, it contains a `circle` and `path`. when a user click on the button, the `path` and `circle` should be grow. on load both of them should be not visible.

I don't have any idea whether i need to animate with `group` or each child of that. At present on `click` i am transforming the group. but how to apply the above effect to children?

any one suggest me the correct way to get this done?

code :

```
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr({width:300,height:300});

 var pathinfo = [{x:0, y:0},{x:0, y:110}];

var group = svg.append('svg:g').attr({
    'width':100,
    'height':100,
    'transform' : 'translate(30, 50)'
});

var d3line2 = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d){return d.x;})
                .y(function(d){return d.y;})
                .interpolate("linear"); 

group.append('circle').attr({'r':30})
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, 140)");;

$('button').on('click', function () {
   var g = d3.select('g');
    g.transition()
    .attr("transform", "translate(30, 110)");
});



group.append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", d3line2(pathinfo))
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("fill", "none");
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5w85zbzx/4/)

Comment: You need to select the child element before starting the transition, e.g. `d3.select("g").select("circle").transition()` or directly `d3.select("circle").transition()`.

Comment: What about `path`. and after i completing the` path` transition, I would like to start with `circle` opacity animation using `end`. - can you update in fiddle?  the reason for updating in fiddle to learn best practice.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, here is my try using your idea. but i guess it can be alter by experts. and is it possible to use `defferd` or `when` like `jquery ` here? http://jsfiddle.net/5w85zbzx/5/

Comment: What do you mean by "defferd" and "when"?

Comment: 3gwebtrain, quick question. How where did the svg attributes for the circle center come from?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, i Just ask like in `jQuery` we have the deffered to wait until to complete one animation. as like I asked.

Comment: @canyon289 - i didn't consider about the position here, I am looking for best approach to do this animation. if you want to alter something to get best output that, appreciated.

Comment: @3gwebtrain This is what `.each("end", ...)` is for in D3. You can't use JQuery functions with D3 transitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scale property in addition to translate in the 'transform' property for the group. Check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/5w85zbzx/7/

```
g.transition().attr("transform", "translate(100,50) scale(1.2,1.2)");
```